# .htaccess deny from all except localhost and allow download from specific file on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a folder which is restricted from direct acces by .htaccess .

```
IndexIgnore * 

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

All works fine until I try to make the file accessed from this folder to be downloaded. In `user.php` I have a view code and a download code. The view code works as planned, it displays the video for example. The download code is pretty simple.
Example: `<a href="folder/test.mp4" download>Click here to Download </a>` . 
But when the download starts I get an error `Failed - Forbidden`

The file that has this code is restricted to users only. And this why I want to make the download available in this page only.
How can I do this?

Edit: I have replaced all the code with

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(mp4|jpg)$ - [F]
```

And now the initial problem persists, but I can't seem to be able to download the content. Also this method works with the display part (that's why I've changed it).

Comment: Aparenty the .htaccess restricted everything, What I saw as working is cache.

Comment: Deny from all trumps allow from local if you first determine denied.

Comment: I tried to change the order and have inserted aditional ip addresses which can be alocated to my domain. Still the same problem

Comment: So you've tried `Order Allow, Deny` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the combinations posible

Comment: I replaced all the code with  `RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule \.(mp4|jpg)$ - [F]`